# Unable to loop through backbone collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, layout-manager

I'm using layout manager with backbone and i'm unable to get models from the collection.
Below is the code. I'm not able to get elements from this.collection.models its shows empty even though the elements are present.

Collection snopshot
[image]

```
//Models
App.Models.StoreModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

//Featured Products Collections
App.Collections.StoreFeaturedProducts = Backbone.Collection.extend({  

    model : App.Models.StoreModel,
    url:"../JSON/products.json",
    parse : function(response){
        return response.products;  
    }

});


//In Router 
this.featureList = new App.Collections.StoreFeaturedProducts();     /* initialize featureList */
this.featureView = new App.Views.DisplayView2({collection : this.featureList}); /* create featureSlider View object */
App.Layouts.AppLayout.insertViews({     /* insert view to layout */
            "wrapper2" : this.featureView
});

this.featureList.fetch();   /* fetch json */

//Render Layout
App.Layouts.AppLayout.render();

//View![enter image description here][2]
App.Views.DisplayView2 = Backbone.View.extend({

    template : '#view1',

    initialize : function(options) {
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
        //this.model.bind('reset', this.render, this);
    },


    beforeRender : function() {
            console.log(this.collection) - shows the elements
        this.collection.each(function(m) {
        //does not go through
    }, this);
    }

    serialize : function() {}


});
```

Comment: Can you please post the same portion of the actual code? The one we have here won't run for one and besides there are discrepancies between it and the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

If your really see the elements on the line where your wrote:

```
console.log(this.collection) - shows the elements
```

that particular array should be accessed through the collections' `models` property:

```
_.each(this.collection.models, function(m) {
    // ...
});
```

Hope this helps.